# magento indexControllor.php url rewriting not working properly

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Hi i build a indexcontrollor in module brand like this

```
class Blank_Brand_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

        echo 'Foo Index Action';
        $this->addaction();
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        echo 'Foo add Action';
        $this->deleteAction();
    }

}
```

When I put in the address: `http://www.myshop.com/index.php/brand/`, it echos Foo Index Action

With this URL, though, it does nothing: `http://www.myshop.com/index.php/brand/add`

What could be the problem here causing this? This could save a lot of problems for me which I have with URL rewriting in Magento!

Answer (score 2):

It's a common oversight.

This url

```
http://www.myshop.com/index.php/brand/
```

is equivalent to this url

```
http://www.myshop.com/index.php/brand/index/index
```

The URI portion "brand" is your module.  The first "index" URI portion is your controller, the second "index" URI portion is your action method.

```
Module:     brand
Controller: index
Action:     index
```

So, let's consider this URL

```
http://www.myshop.com/index.php/brand/add
```

This is equivalent to

```
http://www.myshop.com/index.php/brand/add/index
```

Which gives us

```
Module:     brand
Controller: add
Action:     index
```

The URL you're trying to call is looking for a controller named

```
class Blank_Brand_AddController ....
```

When it doesn't find one, it reports back 404.

If you wanted to call the `addAction` method on your index controller, you'd want the following URL

```
http://www.myshop.com/index.php/brand/index/add
```

Comment: oke so what if i added a param meter too the function addAction($test)

Comment: how would i fill $test because

Comment: also i would like to know how i would pass on a variabele in the index...how would the full url look if $test would be 9 and the add function would not existed.... cos i dont seem to get the right url here...i would like to pass on catid/3 in the index function but how do i do this?

Comment: Request variables don't come into the controller via action method paramaters.  Call "var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams());" in an action controller and it should be self explanatory how to access your request data.  Also, read through the Knowledge Base Developer's tutorial. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on this - perhaps it would help:  http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Comment: +1 for good information, but the original poster isn't trying to to override anything. They're trying to setup their own controller and getting tripped up because it does't work like cake or code igniter. (Also, there's a better way to handle controller overrides these days: http://web-magician.blogspot.com/2009/04/secret-feature-of-magento-13-sharing.html)